# Osgi bundle in start phase but not getting active

Tags: osgi-bundle

My OSGi bundle is giving me strange behaviour. Some times it gets Active in first go and some time I need to restart Karaf again and again to see whether my bundle is active or not. Even I cann't see any exception. And all other bundles are active. Can anyone suggest me what can be the cause. I checked its headers they are just ok, we are importing all the packages and exporting none. As is the case for my bundle. Even I hit start command many times. But it is not getting Active state.

Answer (score 0):

Installation order of your bundles might not be aligned to their dependency orders. Try creating your own feature.xml file, where you can set the installation order of your bundles during startup. You can find more detail at https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/provisioning
And do not forget to add the features you have created to $KARAF_ROOT/etc/org.apache.karaf.features file in order to make your features installed automatically during startup.